# Emploi de « le » comme article indéfini

Tags: articles

Pourquoi emploie-t-on *le* ici

> *Le chien est l’ami de **l’**‌ֹhomme.*

mais *un* ici:

> *La capitale est le cœur d’**un** pays*.

Je ne comprends pas la différence entre ces exemples : dans les deux cas, le nom (*homme* et *pays*) est employé dans un sens général.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we talk about "*Man*" as mankind, we use "*l'homme*". "*Un homme*" would be a particular, single man. Every sentence referring to man as mankind will always be "*l'homme*". This holds true for animals among other things.

> L'ours est un animal solitaire

Or simply like "the dog" in the beginning of the sentence.

It makes sense to say "*un*" for a country, because it's true for each and every country, individually. The difference is subtle, you can even say "*du /de l'*" instead of "*d'un*" sometimes :

> Les quatre côtés **du** carré ont une longueur égale
>
> Les quatre côtés **d'un** carré ont une longueur égale

Both are correct. Remember that for a statement with man as in mankind, always use "*l'homme*".

Comment: "mankind" is "l'Homme", with a capital "H".